# Is it possible to define two-different color for dashed stroke like selection box in Photoshop?

Tags: wpf, graphics

Currently, I can create polygon-based selection box that has only one color on dashed stroke like the following photo.

[image]

In the other hand, all photo editors has selection box like the following photo.

[image]

Is it possible to do this in WPF 4.0 without use double border in same place (two polygon objects place in the same location with different dash offset and stroke color).

Answer (score 2):

just a suggestion, you can draw a rectangle with solid stroke then draw the dashed rectangle on top :)